# Scala Sans font

Tags: fonts

How can I get Scala Sans font in LaTeX for beamer?  I went through the [LaTeX Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) and I couldn't find it.  Perhaps it is named different?

**Note**:

I want to use some fonts for a PhD workplan presentation.  There is no template, so font choosing is very flexible.  I was asking for Scala Sans because a graphic designer friend of mine suggested it, but I'm completely open to new suggestions.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could find any Scala subfamily in a LaTeX archive as it's a [commercial font](http://www.martinmajoor.com/1_scala.html).

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Perhaps there is a similar alternative?

Comment: I doubt it. I spent a long time trying to find an alternative myself. In the end I bought [Nexus](http://www.martinmajoor.com/4_nexus.html), which is from the same type designer, but cheaper, and IMO nicer. See for example, these [examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends/46348#46348).

Comment: One more comment. When I wrote that I spent a long time looking, I should have mentioned that I was looking for a _typeface family_ (not just a sans serif) that had a good serif, a good sans serif, and a very good typewriter. If you're just looking for a good sans serif, similar to _Scala,_ this may be easier to find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*> Perhaps there is a similar alternative?*

define ›similar‹ `:-)` ...Scala Sans was a rather original design without any direct predecessors when it came out, and while it may have spawned a few epigones, there still isn't really a typeface that's similar enough to be mistaken for it, except, to the untrained eye, Majoor's own Nexus and Seria.

Other faces from roughly the same category (neo-humanist sans) that are available at no charge include [Lucida Sans](http://www.identifont.com/samples/adobe/LucidaSans.gif), Adobe's Frutiger clone [Myriad](http://www.identifont.com/samples/adobe/MyriadPro.gif), their recent [Source Sans](http://www.identifont.com/samples/adobe/SourceSansPro.gif) (not really humanist though). And why not check out Microsoft's recent system fonts as well? They include Microsoft's own Frutiger clone Segoe, [Corbel](http://www.identifont.com/samples/microsoft/Corbel.gif), and [Candara](http://www.identifont.com/samples/microsoft/Candara.gif), a proper neo-humanist sans with a decent italic.

A rather recent addition to the TeX Font Catalogue is [Cabin](http://www.impallari.com/cabin). Two styles, four weights, true small caps. It may not be able to compete with Scala, particularly when it comes to the italics, but out of the fonts from that catalogue, it's as close as you can get.

[image]

[image]