# Alternatives to FF Nexus

Tags: fonts, typography

I am very fond of the fonts M.R.C. van Dongen used to typeset his book *LaTeX and Friends*. I believe it is the same as Hatcher uses for his books (for instance *Algebraic Topology*), and also the one in which the *Princeton Mathematical Companion* is written. It is called **FF Nexus**, and it costs 200$. Here's what [FF Nexus](http://www.martinmajoor.com/pdf/overview_nexus.pdf) looks like.

Is there a free alternative, that contains very similar fonts?

Comment: as Nexus is an almost identical, a bit more playful, twin of Scala (by the same designer), I suggest you have a look at Cabin, and this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117925/scala-sans-font (of which I think your Q might be considered a duplicate).

Comment: Is ‘the Princeton Mathematical Companion’ [The Princeton Companion to Mathematics](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt7sd01)? My PDF copy says (on p. iv) “This book has been composed in LucidaBright”, and the [Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org) `pdffonts` program agrees that it's Lucida Bright (apparently with a little Helvetica and Times Roman).